# Power Analysis for Time Series Models (ARIMA and neural network)

Tags: r, time-series, neural-networks, arima, statistical-power

In short, I am building **ARIMA** (AutoRegressive Integrated Moving Average) and **neural network time series** (to be more specific, I am using the nnetar() function in R) models to make **regression predictions**, and am **wondering whether power analysis is necessary**. Most of the machine-learning/data science papers on making either regression predictions seem to use MAE (Mean Absolute Error) and MRSE (Mean Square Root Error) to measure performance, and I have not seen any power analysis on any of the machine-learning papers that I have looked through.

However, I work with people in health care, and in many clinical trials, power analysis is important: for example, many randomized clinical trials would report something like " Samples of size n1=232 and n2= 232 will ensure that the test of hypothesis will have 80% power to detect a 5 unit difference in mean systolic blood pressures in patients receiving the new drug as compared to patients receiving the placebo." And these people would continue to ask me how many samples I would need for my models to make my predictions at 80% power. I do not have answers to these questions. I tried to look up ways to do power analysis on ARIMA and neural network time series models but textbooks don't have this information and I only found a few theoretical, academic papers for specific cases that I do not think necessarily apply to my case.

More specifically, I am using the ARIMA (AutoRegressive Integrated Moving Average) and neural network models to fit my train data from 2014 to 2018, then to make predictions against my 2019 test data. My objective is to find an ARIMA or neural network model that best describes my data from 2014 to 2018 (performance measured by Mean Absolute Error (MAE) and Mean Square Root Error (MSRE)), and then using that model to make predictions for 2019.

Let's say my hypothesis is the more we are exposed to certain types of radiations --let's say type A,B, and C -- the more likely we will develop cancerous tumors. I am trying to figure out which type of radiation contributes the most to development of cancerous tumors. I am not looking to make predictions at individual levels but how many hours we are exposed to each type of radiations A,B, and C per give Quarter (i.e. 3 months) in a given population is associated with cancerous tumor detection rates per a given Quarter (i.e. 3 months) in that population.

So I am first building times series models with cancerous tumor detection rates per quarter. Then I would add as exogenous regressor variables different types of radiations to improve the models. I am also conducting cross-correlation to identify the time lag between exposure to radiations and tumor development. The exogenous regressor variables would be added in a lagged fashion if meaningful time lags are identified from cross-correlation.

I am using MAE and MRSE to identify the most optimal model. I would also have to be careful about overfitting; I would have to measure the difference in each model's performance in test data and train data and set criteria (e.g., if the difference in performance between the test and train data is over 20%) to reject overfitted models.

**I don't think I need to run a power analysis** because 1) I have not seen power analysis in this kind of regression prediction research in any machine-learning papers; 2) One of the reasons people do power analysis is to figure out how many patients one needs to recruit in a randomized clinical trial. But I am running a retrospective, large-data machine-learning study.

**But since every clinical person** I run into in the health care industry **asks me the same question about "power analysis**," I was **wondering whether I am missing something**.